# Evaluate and simplify different quotients $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Evaluate and simplify different quotients $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ where $h\neq 0$ and $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ where $x\neq a$ for each of the following functions.

> a. $f(x)=x^2-2x$
>
> b. $f(x)=4-5x$
>
> c. $f(x)=x^3+2$
>
> d. $f(x)=\frac{7}{x+3}$

Hi, all. I tried looking through my notes for these exercises, but unfortunately, I cannot find them. Can someone please explain how to do at least one of these questions? Thank you! I greatly appreciate any advice/solutions.

NOTE: Also, I kind of forgot what those quotient functions things are. Can someone please explain to me what in the world are they? Thanks again! :)

Comment: Just a clarification: when I look at this question, I'm really confused. What's $h$?

Comment: $h$ is just a perturbation of $x$

Comment: There are tons of similar questions under "related" on the right side of your screen.  Also you can search: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=difference+quotient  .  There are tons of resources online, just use Google.

Comment: @mathematician, oh thanks!

Comment: Problem: Google is not loading so RIP.

Comment: I'll just use the "related" questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will do b) as an example.   $$f(x)=4-5x$$   gives
\begin{align}
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} &= \frac{4-5(x+h)-(4-5x)}{h} \\
&= \frac{4-5x+5x-5h-4}{h} \\ &= \frac{-5h}{h} \\ &= -5.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Just insert the specific $f(x)$ in $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$:

b) gives 
$$\frac{4-5(x+h)-(4-5x)}{h}=\frac{-5h}{h}=-5$$

EDIT: As per OP's request, these things are called "difference quotients" and when you take the limit $h\rightarrow 0$ or (in the other case) $x\rightarrow a$, you get the derivative $\frac{df}{dx}$.

Comment: picked the linear example as well i see :p

Comment: @qbert Damn, you beat me to it! :) (+1)

Comment: OH, THAT'S WHAT IT MEANS? I got so confused by the other questions. Thank you so much!

Comment: just barely haha

Answer (score 1):

as example for  $a)$ 
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}&=& \frac{(x+h)^2-2(x+h)-(x^2-2x)}{h}\\
&=& \frac{x^2+h^2+2xh-2x-2h-x^2+2x}{h}\\
&=& \frac{h^2+2xh-2h}{h}\\
&=& \frac{2xh+h^2}{h}-\frac{2h}{h}\\
&=& 2x+h-2
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: The final answer is in that form? Oh, I thought that it had to be an actual number! Thanks!

Comment: you see that we can't develop the last line, but if we take $h$ to zero we will get the derivative of $f$ where we don't see any $h$ in the formulation

Comment: Everything's starting to come back to me—starting to remember this stuff again! Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

- $c)$

\begin{align}
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} &= \frac{(x+h)^3 +2 -x^3 -2}{h} \\ &= \frac{3x^2h +3xh^2 +h^3}{h} \\ &= 3x^2 +3xh +h^2
\end{align}

- $d)$

\begin{align}
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} &= \frac{\dfrac{7}{x+h+3} -\dfrac{7}{x+3}}{h} \\ &= \frac{7(x+3-x-h-3)}{h(x+3)(x+h+3)} \\ &= -\frac{7}{(x+3)(x+h+3)}
\end{align}

Comment: I think you made a typo! :P

Comment: where exactly??

Comment: I think you fixed it! d) to c)!

Answer (score 1):

No-ones showing the second quotient:

a) $f(x) = x^2 - 2x$

So

\begin{align}
\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} &= \frac{(x +h)^2 -  2(x-h) - x^2 + 2x}{h} \\
&= \frac{x^2 + 2hx + h^2 - 2x - 2h - x^2 + 2x}h \\
&= \frac{2hx + h^2 - 2h}h \\
&= 2x +h - 2
\end{align}

And for the other

\begin{align}
\frac{f(x) -f(a)}{x-a} &= \frac{x^2 -2x -a^2 +2a}{x-a} \\
&= \frac{(x^2 -a^2) - (2x -2a)}{x-a} \\
&= \frac{(x+a)(x-a) - 2(x-a)}{x-a} \\
&= \frac{((x+a) -2)(x-a)}{x-a} \\
&= x +a -2
\end{align}

Notice if you replace $a$ with $x + h$, get the same thing.

====

(This is all hinting toward learning about derivatives in calculus by the way.)

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}h = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} (2x +h -2) = 2x -2$$

and

$$\lim_{a\rightarrow x}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{h} = \lim_{a\rightarrow x} (x +a - 2) = x + x -2= 2x -2$$

=====

If you think of what these equations are doing graphically$\ldots$

They are taking two points, dividing the vertical change in value by the horizontal change in value.  In other words, they are taking the slope of the line between these points.

What happens if the points get very close together?  If $h$ becomes tiny or $x -a$ becomes tiny?  Then this is the slope of two points on the graph very close together.  As $h$ approaches zero or $a$ approaches $x$ this will become very close to the slope of the tangent line at $x$ of the function.

That's why these quotients are a big deal.

Comment: Wow, thanks! @fleablood